# Why MFTEnumEx() corrupts the stack?

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

Down below you can see some dummy code for enumerating available multiplexers. On my system there is only one mux available (as expected).
When I call the MFTEnumEx(), the function succeeds, but stack gets corrupted. That's why I added that 64k buffer. 16 bytes will be written at offset 16. I tried this code on two different machines with the same result (Windows 10). Can somebody explain this?

```
    BYTE buff[ 65536 ];
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitialize( NULL );
    ATLASSERT( SUCCEEDED( hr ) );
    hr = MFStartup( MF_VERSION, MFSTARTUP_FULL );
    ATLASSERT( SUCCEEDED( hr ) );

    IMFActivate ** ppActivate = NULL;
    UINT numActivate = 0;

    hr = MFTEnumEx( MFT_CATEGORY_MULTIPLEXER,
                    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ASYNCMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE |
                    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_FIELDOFUSE | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_LOCALMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_TRANSCODE_ONLY,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &ppActivate,
                    &numActivate );
```

Comment: The code runs fine. If you have stack corruption then you trimmed the corrupting code.

Comment: Nothing was trimmed. That's the entire code inside the main().

Comment: I put it into `main()` and it worked for me.

Comment: I just figured out that VS2013 has this problem, but when I compile the same code with VS2010, the problem is gone.

Comment: I built with VS2013 and it was good

Comment: it is also possible (i don't know when and why) that declaring a big variable from the stack as in your case `BYTE buff[ 65536 ];` may create some problems

Comment: Does not seem to crash for me on Windows 10 with VS2013 for both x86 and x64. Why not just post the whole sample if this is the only thing inside `main()` - it will still be easier for people to copy and run not add the headers, libraries and stuff.